# Justify text in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRS i have to justify the text in textbox but cant see any option to make it justify. I have tried the custom functions to make it work but none of them works.

Any idea or approach we can do it in a simple way?

I have tried the below solutions

https://www.phidiax.com/blog/post/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-how-to-justify-text-part-2
[Justify text in SQL Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133644/justify-text-in-sql-reporting-services)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to do it in SSRS. Maybe try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703964/justify-in-rdlc/62704667#62704667 but it looks like it wasn't working for some.